# Sulu CMS admin: is there a way to add new content automatically to the "top" of the order list?

Tags: sulu

In a situation where, for instance, a user creates a new `news_item` content under a `news` content that already has several items of the `news_item` type (or any other type, for that matter), the new content will be added to the bottom of the already existing volume of `news_item` content.

However, after adding several dozens of content-items, it's pretty annoying for the user to scroll all the way down to find the most recent item (and then often reorder it to get it all the way to the top).

Is there a setting somewhere that you can manipulate in order to make Sulu add new content *to the top* instead of *to the bottom* of an existing body of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say that this is currently not possible... Except you try to override some behavior, but I don't think that can be done in a reasonable amount of time...

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)